# The pig latin translation

Tags: ruby

I am trying to solve the "pig latin problem" in the [Test-First](http://testfirst.org/) Ruby lessons.

In this program I am basically trying to translate a string with the following rules:

1. If a word begins with a vowel sound, add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.
2. If a word begins with a consonant sound, move it to the end of the word, and then add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.

For this I wrote the following code which worked fine:

```
def translate(word)
  words=word.split(" ")
  words.each do |x|
    if ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?x[0,1]
      x << ("ay")
    else
      x << ("#{x[0,1]}ay")
      x[0,1]=""
    end
  end
  words.join(" ")
end
```

However, the problem also states that when translating words with 2, or 3 consonants in the beginning, it should move them all at the end of the word, and then add "ay".

For that I ended an `until` loop into the `else` statement:

```
def translate(word)
  words=word.split(" ")
  words.each do |x|
    if ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?x[0,1]
      x << ("ay")
    else
      until ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?x[0,1]
        x << ("#{x[0,1]}")
        x[0,1]=""
      end
      x << ("#{x[0,1]}ay")
    end
  end
  words.join(" ")
end
```

This is giving me this result:

```
translate("the bridge over the river kwai")
=> "etheay idgebriay overay etheay iverriay aikwaay"
```

So, it is running the `until` loop one extra time and adding the first vowel in the word to the end as well. However, it is not removing this vowel from the first position.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's this line: `x << ("#{x[0,1]}ay")`.

You've already shaved off the consonants from the beginning of the word so that it starts with a vowel, and then you're adding that vowel (`"#{x[0,1]}"`) to the end along with the `ay`.

So, replace `x << ("#{x[0,1]}ay")` with just `x << "ay"` and it should work.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the `if` there in this case.

Answer (score 3):

(*NOTE: technically this is not an answer*)

Your original code is not very idiomatic. You're running `while` loops and mutating strings in-place. You don't see that in good ruby code. May I offer you an improved version?

```
def vowel?(str)
  ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?(str)
end

def translate_word(word)
  first_vowel_idx = word.chars.find_index{|c| vowel?(c)}
  leading_consonants = word[0..first_vowel_idx-1]
  rest_of_the_word = word[first_vowel_idx..-1]
  rest_of_the_word + leading_consonants + 'ay'
end

def translate(sentence)
  words = sentence.split(" ")
  words.map{|w| translate_word(w) }.join(" ")
end

translate("the bridge over the river kwai") # => "ethay idgebray overoveray ethay iverray aikway"
```

Comment: I like your approach, but would be inclined to replace `vowel?(c)` with `c =~ /[aeiou]/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: How is it more general? It does one thing only (and puts a speaking name to it).

Comment: `c =~ /[aeiou]/` is also writable as `c[/[aeiou]/]` but Sergio makes a good point about readability. Speed is the reason for using a regex, rather than iterating over the array of vowels, sacrificing readability.

Comment: I edited out the reason I gave before you posted your comment. Considering that you invoke `vowel?(c)` but once, and my suggested replacement is short and equally comprehendable (no?), I didn't think there was a need for a method there. Definitely a fine point, and matter of taste. (I did give you 10 points. :-|) @theTinMan: thank you for the comment, the first clause in particular--I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: in a previous version of code, `vowel?` was used several times. Now it can be inlined, yes. But I'd still hesitate. It's a nice abstraction.